# my comment got removed, no idea why

Tags: support, comments

I often see posts where the user assumed something weird, like "I assume the bug must be here", "I assume the rest of the code is fine", "I assume that's how the API works". In those cases, I tend to use the famous movie quote `"Assumption is the mother of all *****"`.

So today I've incidentally found out that my comment was removed here: [kill a specific thread in GDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23237354/kill-a-specific-thread-in-gdb). I posted the comment again, and again but it got removed. Then I left a bigger comment:

"Here I assumed" - Assumption is the mother of all *****................... note: this is a famous quote, and hits the nail on the head! Whoever removed my comment (several times), I would like to know the WHY. I really don't understand WHY it was removed. Please leave your message here!

It was removed again, without any reply. Can somebody tell me what's going on? I really have no idea. I don't see how this can be offending. For a second, I thought maybe there's some automated system, and "****" is considered a curse word, but... come on...

Comment: Let's for a moment assume that knowledge of that "famous movie quote" is not universal ... what are you then left with?

Comment: Well, all else aside, I fail to see how that comment is adding significant value.  Even if one doesn't consider it offensive, it would still be just noise, and worthy of deletion on those grounds.  Comments are second class citizens after all.

Comment: Closely related: [Are expletives, cursing, swear words, or vulgar language allowed on SE sites?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22232)

Comment: @Bart: I don't think that quote requires previous knowledge of the movie. Honestly, I see only one way to interpret it, "don't assume things you haven't verified".

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Yet without the particular background, to me it comes off as snarky and potentially even rude.

Comment: There are possibly 13 year olds (or lower) using SO. :)

Comment: Certainly not younger than 13 @gitsitgo ... well, not openly at least.

Comment: @Bart: I know, some people take comments as personal insults..... (just to say something *I* would consider snarky and rude)

Comment: Probably because it uses foul language.  Not everyone drops F-bombs.  And Steven Seagal movies are terrible, btw.  What's your definition of "famous"?

Comment: What's the famous movie where they mentioned the quote.

Comment: It is really that important you are allowed to swear? The site generally frowns upon curse words, so it moderates them away. If you want to swear take it elsewhere potty-mouth.

Comment: What I find bizarrely hilarious is that apparently you assumed this would be widely recognized, or at least easily understood in the proper sense.

Answer (score 42):

> the famous movie quite "Assumption is the mother of all *******"

Famous? /me googles ... ah Under Siege 2. Never seen it, don't know it. The comment doesn't seem to add much to the question and can surely be phrased more constructively. And though I don't get flustered by it personally, there are plenty of users who don't like any form of f*ck on any post on the site. Overall I see no reason why it should be preserved.

> note: this is a famous quote, and hits the nail on the head! whoever removed my comment (several times), I would like to know the WHY. I really don't understand WHY it was removed. please leave your message here!

If you have to add that much information to have your comment make any sense and to try to preserve it, ... you might want to consider leaving a different comment.

Comment: "The comment doesn't seem to add much to the question " - for me it adds a lot because it shows a fundamental flaw in the thinking process of the OP.... assuming(X) you can interpret it. It looks like I assumed to much LOL. Should I leave the original quote there and add some explanation, or write something completely different?

Comment: I'd go for something completely different. I get the point you're trying to make, but the way you're making it is not great. If you'd say something like "Don't assume, make sure you verify" and then even extend that, you'll have something of lasting value. (Well, as lasting as comments will ever be)

Comment: @KarolyHorvath [xkcd comics](https://xkcd.com/1339/) get pretty good reactions around here, and this one seems to cover your situation pretty well.

Comment: I prefer "The Siege" to "Under Siege". *This is the land of opportunity, gentlemen. The opportunity to turn yourselves in.*

Comment: @WendiKidd: does it? I prefer the movie quote, you cannot get the idea more condensed than that. oh well, to each his own.

Comment: Movie quotes are only useful if the person reading it has the same familiarity with movies as you do.  I wouldn't assume that is usually true at Stack Overflow (which is international, and has a lot of age-variety also).

Comment: "I am in bit of a paradox for I have assumed there is no point in assuming."  By the same person who first coined the phrase "Assumption is the mother of all screw-ups".

Answer (score 32):

What's weird about this is that no moderators removed your comments (although we would have).

After checking with Shog, your comments were subject to a 1-flag deletion because they contained forbidden words.

As a friendly tip: Don't curse in comments.

Answer (score 14):

Comments are flaggable as "not constructive" or as "rude or offensive."  The word is profanity and probably not appropriate for SO, so it is flaggable as "offensive."  Also, it isn't a clear pointer that is helpful to answer the question, so it is probably "not constructive."  It isn't even clear that you were directly responding to that component of the post.

If the poster's assumptions were shaky, it would have been helpful to explain why in a way that is clear to the poster.

FYI, I'm not familiar with this quote.

Comment: Donnow, but for what folks said, almost no one is familiar with the fracking quote :P

Answer (score 8):

Comments are second-class citizens. They are not suppose to hold any true weight or important content. That information should go in the question or answers.

But at the end of the day, ask yourself: does it matter that my comment was deleted? Does it *really* matter?

And you should say to yourself: no.

Comments keep increasing the page length, and can get in the way of finding the content a user really cares about: the answers. The pure, unobscured answers. This is a Q&A site, not a forum.

Comment: do they *really* matter? actually, they do...

Comment: @KarolyHorvath, do movie quotes and side jokes really matter? They just get in the way.

Comment: it wasn't meant to be a joke nor a pure movie quote.

Comment: Why using that dirty quote. You can clarify with clean words, I'm sure you can find those in English language.

Comment: "Comments are second-class citizens. They are not suppose to hold any true weight or important content. That information should go in the question or answers." - do you have a quote to that policy? Because when I tried to edit answers that were no longer accurate due to API changes, I was slapped on the wrist, and told to make a note of that in the comments.