# Is masked profanity allowed on SO (or *.se)

Tags: discussion

I submitted an edit to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11752631/auto-completion-search-with-solr-using-ngrams) to clean up a masked expletive. The edit was approved, but later rolled back.

The Meta topic [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251885/my-comment-got-removed-no-idea-why/251886#251886) and this [SE topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/are-expletives-cursing-swear-words-or-vulgar-language-allowed-on-se-sites) show that the language on this family of sites is expected to be professional.

Does the same hold true for masked expletives?

*The phrase "masked expletive", in my vocabulary, means a word that is ordinarily considered profane in polite company, but written with odd characters like wildcards or 1337 h@x0r $p3@k. (in this case, f star star k)*

Comment: The edit did more than replace the expletive though.

Comment: In this case, the exact content of the search results are actually core to the question asked; there is really no need to replace those.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, Okay, but why roll back the whole edit? The exact content of the search result don't really matter, as long as it's close. If the asterisks were the issue, then let them be replaced with another asterisk phrase.

Comment: For the record, I don't disagree with most of [the other edits you've made](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1195835/tecbrat?tab=activity&sort=revisions) (other than perhaps the fact that for many of these, the systematical searching and editing of expletives generates *more* attention to those expletives than they would have if they had been well left alone.) But do use common sense in edge cases.

Comment: Edited in response to your edit

Comment: @Pekka웃 Thank you. And yes, I saw one instance and decided to do some cleanup. It might strike you as "silly", but to me it was making the site more professional. **Pardon the chat**, but: I heard a story of someone in a call center who got fired because her monitoring system included screenshots and a screenshot captured profanity on her screen. We'd like to prevent similar issues.

Comment: While, as said, it is *mostly* fine to edit profanities and professional language is strongly recommended at all times, we do not have to cater to every insanity out there. Policies like that are not our responsibility. What if I took offense to your using "brat" and renamed your user name to "TecUnrulyChild"?

Comment: Ok, you made me laugh.

Comment: All this editing and nobody removed Thanks in Advance and the signature?

Comment: And, as it turns out, a whole lot of i and im and general wiffle-waffle? This is why I rail against minor edits. If we care enough to remove not only swear words but also masked swear words, why can't we clean up accidental headings, messed up use of code blocks, grammar, punctuation, spelling, and meta talk? Those were all hurting the question way more than four letters in the sample output (which were caused by search results and not chosen/typed by the OP.)

Comment: @KateGregory You are absolutely correct. I was rushing through trying to do a specific thing across many posts and therefor did not do all I should have on the given post. Another of my peeves that I'll go and edit out are begging phrases "Please help me!" But I agree I should **slow down** and see if I can improve the entire post while I'm at it. (I also tend to fix lower case "i" and "its","it's" errors.)

Comment: Searching for and censoring already censored words... has it really come to this?

Comment: Disappointed if not surprised to see the phenomenon continuing of people downvoting perfectly well formed questions on MSO apparently because they implicitly challenge/propose a practice that others hold sacrosanct/offensive.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin Downvotes on MSO don't hurt anything. I take it no differently than a comment that disagrees with the point made by the question.

Comment: @TecBrat Glad they don't bother you. :-)  I think they are incredibly counterproductive, for reasons discussed elsewhere.

Answer (score 12):

Generally, the language used on these sites is indeed expected to be clean and professional: anyone using the f-word in their regular speech will have it edited or removed.

That definitely includes masked expletives in the context of a question text. Replacing, say,

> I have no f**ing idea why this doesn't work

with a less strong word is fine (unless it's prudent to remove the sentence altogether, as you often [correctly] do in your editing).

But there are limits. The issue in question is the name of a Canadian indie band. The OP already went through the effort of masking the word. Editing that any further makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: inb4 lance​​​​​

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not get in before an offensive flag. Hopefully the flag was raised in irony.

Comment: Nah @BoltClock. I always raise those on Pekka's content. I mean, just look at the guy.

Answer (score 4):

Ideally there shouldn't be any need for expletives masked or otherwise on a professional site. Including them runs the risk of the site being blocked by over-zealous filters.

The easiest thing to do is edit them out.

However, in this case the expletive (masked or not) *appears* to be essential to the problem being reported. The OP should have chosen a different word starting with "f" to illustrate the point, and I can see why someone would roll back the edit.

Changing the code in a question runs the risk of removing the reason the code is failing.

In cases like this leave a comment with the edit to explain what you've done and allow the OP to sort it out properly.